# TableView null value? Fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: swift

I am making a program that reads messages from a database.

Every 10 seconds the program downloads the data into an array.

But there is sometimes a problem.. sometimes my app random throws an error "Fatal error: Index out of range"

It is (i think) because sometimes the URLSession gives back null value to myMessages.messages or i don't know:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return myMessages.messages.count

    }
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myOwnCell", for: indexPath) as! MyOwnCell

        // Sometimes here occours a bug:indexpath.row and myMessages.messages.count are equal to 0
        let message = myMessages.messages[indexPath.row]
 }
 ...
```

I tried something:

Printing out myMessages.messages, myMessages.messages.count and indexPath

In a normal case the results are like this (with 2 messages):

```
[<App.BubbleMessage: 0x1c066bc40>, <App.BubbleMessage: 0x1c0678e40>] //messages
2 //messages count
[0, 0] //indexPath
[<App.BubbleMessage: 0x1c066bc40>, <App.BubbleMessage: 0x1c0678e40>]
2
[0, 1]
```

And then sometimes an error occours:

```
[]
0
[0, 0]
```

And this generates the error. Is there some work around?:C

**Update**:

If I manually remove all messages from myMessages.messages then it is still working

```
[] //messages
0 //messages count
```

and the cellForRowAt function will not be called.. so I don't know

Why is it, if I manually create an empty array then it doesn't call the cellForRowAt function,

but sometimes Even that the array is still empty it calls it and throws an error. why?

Is there any way to prevent it from happening?

```
if (myMessages.messages.count == 0){ return }
```

?

**UPDATE 2**: It is possible that

Into the array was loaded 2 messages (msg1, msg2)

Now the cellForRowAt function generates the first one: msg1

but while it is generating msg1, the data loaded from server somehow containts only 1 message -> therefore myMessagges.messages will be removedAll() and updated with only 1 value.

So next time when cellForRowAt looks for msg2 at rowNumber 2, it doesn't find it.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use `DispatchQueue.main.async` in your `URLSession` callback?

`URLSession` uses background thread to call API, and UI must be on the main thread (dispatch queue).

Second issue, if you really use `DispatchQueue.main.async`, there could be another issue which is a thread race.

Imagine the following scenario

```
// 1
myMessages.messages.append(contentsOf: [message1, message2])

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // 2
    tableView.insertRows( /* put here code for insertion of two rows */)
}

// 3
myMessages.messages.append(message3)

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // 4
    tableView.insertRows( /* put here code for insertion of one rows */)
}
```

What will happen?

```
1 is executed
then 3
then 2 then 4
```

That means

```
- append to the backend array 2 object
- then append to the backend array 1 object
(now the array has 3 objects inserted, not 2)
- then inform the tableview that 2 objects are inserted
- then inform the tableview that another object is inserted
```

This makes the table view crash, when he is informed of only adding 2 objects while the backend (when he calls numberOfRowsInSection) gets a different number {3 inserted}

The solution is to use a bit of immutability. Take a snapshot of the array and pass it to the dispatch queue to be the new backend of the tableview.

```
// 1
myMessages.messages.append(contentsOf: [message1, message2])

let snapshot = myMessages.messages

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // 2
    self.backendArray = snapshot // Just take the snapshot that is
                                 // captured from the out of the closure
    tableView.insertRows( /* put here code for insertion of two rows */)
}

// 3
myMessages.messages.append(message3)

// Take another snapshot, must be different from the first
let snapshot2 = myMessages.messages

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // 4
    self.backendArray = snapshot2 // Just take the second snapshot that is
                                  // captured from the out of the
    tableView.insertRows( /* put here code for insertion of one rows */)
}
```

And use `backendArray` as your backend (in numberOfRows and cellForRowAt) instead of the real object.

Now you take a snapshot of the array every time you call dispatch main, so even if the calculations / fetching still have more, your tableview datasource will be consistent with the UI

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, it was really this problem!